# Where does {exp:calendar:events...} know where to get data from?

Tags: loop, calendar-events

I am very new to EE so please be gentle.

I have 3 template files, all with some static content and then this code:

```
{exp:calendar:events calendar_id="52" sort="asc" dynamic="off" status="current"}
// HTML, outputting the fields
{/exp:calendar:events}
```

Now the only difference in the code in each file is the calendar_id="number" (numbers are 52,114,117). So this is where the code specifies which entries to display. Okay got it.

But what I want to know is if I created a channel in the future, and created a template. In that template I wanted to output the entries, how would I know which "calendar_id" to reference?

Answer (score 1):

One quick and easy way to glean a Calendar ID is just to go to 
*CP > Add-ons > Modules > Calendar > Calendars* and look at the output there. It gives you a list of all your calendars by name, and includes Calendar ID's.

[image: Calendar table]